# How return default text in label after some time?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have label with text, after push the button i have another text in label. How after some time return default text in label?

Comment: With a `delay` or a Timer?

Comment: I think timer will be better solution, but i want to see all possible solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a delay change text in label:
(This will update your text after 60 Sec.)

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 60) {
    //your label text text: label.text = "your text"
}
```

Timer task:
(This will call the "resetLabel" method after every 5 Sec.)

```
let timerTask = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(resetLabel), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

@objc func resetLabel() {
//your label text text: label.text = "your text"
}
```